# Strange error in code: stray '\239', '\187', and '\191', and in program

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compilation, syntax-error

#### My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *str, c;
    int x = 0, y = 1;

    str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

    printf("Inserisci stringa principale: ");

    while (c != '\n')
    {
        // Read the input from keyboard standard input
        c = getc(stdin);

        // Re-allocate (resize) memory for character read to be stored
        str = (char*)realloc(str, y * sizeof(char));

        // Store read character by making pointer point to c
        str[x] = c;

        x++;
        y++;
    }

    str[x] = '\0'; // At the end append null character to mark end of string

    printf("\nLa stringa inserita: %s", str);

    char *sub, b;
    int w = 0, z = 1;

    sub = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

    printf("Immetti sottostringa da cercare: ");

    while (b != '\n')
    {
        // Read the input from keyboard standard input
        b = getc(stdin);

        // Re-allocate (resize) memory for character read to be stored
        sub = (char*)realloc(sub, z * sizeof(char));

        // Store read character by making pointer point to c
        sub[w] = b;

        w++;
        z++;
    }

    sub[w] = '\0'; // At the end append null character to mark end of string

    char *p1, *p2, *p3;
    int i=0, j=0, flag=0, occurrences=0;

    p1 = str;
    p2 = sub;

    for(i = 0+1; i<strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if(*p1 == *p2)
        {
            p3 = p1;

            for(j = 0; j<strlen(sub); j++)
            {
                if(*p3 == *p2)
                {
                    p3++;
                    p2++;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            p2 = sub;
            if(j + 1 == strlen(sub))
            {
                flag = 1;
                occurrences = occurrences + 1;
                printf("\nnel numero di volte : %d\n",occurrences );
                printf("\nSottostringa trovata all'indice : %d\n",i );
            }
        }
        p1++;
    }

    if(flag==0)
    {
         printf("Sottostringa non trovata");
    }

    free(str);
    free(sub);
    return (0);
}
```

I receive this error when I try to compile:

```
myfile.h:1: error: stray '\239' in program
myfile.h:1: error: stray '\187' in program
myfile.h:1: error: stray '\191' in program
```

I tried to find a solution, but I had absolutely no idea what this was, this error.

I tried to compile a lot of times, and every time I received this error. Why?

Comment: What is `myfile.h` ? Did you put your code in a .h file ???

Comment: I suggest you do a hex. dump of `my file.h`.  Did you create it using a non-text format?

Comment: Aside: your memory is too small to hold the terminator, the first time of `realloc(str, y * sizeof(char))` the variable `y` is `1`, the same size as previously allocated. Please move `y++;` up to before the reallocation.

Comment: @PaulR is a generic name on cmd display another name+

Comment: no my file name is .c i write this in generic

Comment: What kind of text editor did you use to create `myfile.h` ? Maybe it did insert some mon ASCII characters in it and make it un-usable to compile.

Comment: BTW if you did nit include your `myfile.h` file so I hope it is not the file where you put the code in...

Comment: My comment still applies regardless of what the filename is.  Which editor did you use to create or edit the file, and how was it saved?

Comment: @frankjones next time: write  "This is my file myfile.h" instead of "This is my code". Then it's clear. And BTW the .h file extension is used for header files only. So if your file is called "myfunnyfilename.c" dont change the extension to .h as this only creates confusion.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) do not cast the returned value.  It has type `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code , making it much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  3) when using `realloc()`, always assign the returned value to a temp variable, check that temp variable, and if NOT NULL, then assign to the target variable.  Otherwise, if `realloc()` fails, the original pointer is lost, resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest 4 spaces for each indent level.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  Names like `p2`, `p1`, `p3` are meaningless even in the current context.

Comment: when outputting some string to stdout, strongly suggest ending the string with `\n` so the text will be immediately passed on to the terminal, rather than sitting in the (internal) output buffer until a '\n' or `fflush( stdout );` or the program exits.

Comment: the `return` statement is not a function, so no parens are (normally) needed around the returned value.

Comment: the function: `getc()` returns a `int`, not a `char`

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression from the calls to `malloc()` and `realloc()`

Comment: change `char *str;` to `char *str = NULL;`  then can remove the first call to `malloc()`

Comment: the statements: `while (b != '\n' )`   and `while(c != '\n' )`  are undefined behavior because the variable `b` and `c` have an unknown value on the first entry to those loops.  Suggest setting them to a known value, for instance, a space.  Or better yet, change the `while()` loops to `do { ... } while();` loops.

Comment: this expression: `i = 0+1;` is nonsense.  Suggest: `i=0;`   Note that `strlen()` returns a `size_t` value, so the `i` and `j` variables should be declared as `size_t` to avoid any implicit conversions by the compiler

Comment: So in this case, the stray errors are in decimal, not octal (the most common).

Answer (score 4):

The byte-sequence `239`, `187` and `191` is the [UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8).

You have not use a plain text editor, or asked your editor to save using UTF-8 with BOM. Don't do that. Save as *plain text*.

Comment: thank you very much! i use notepad++, now i select format utf without boom and problem is solved