# "git log --encoding=ISO-8859-1" doesn't have any effect

Tags: git, encoding, header, git-log

I have a C project ([ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoded) in the [STM32CubeMX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32#Cortex-M) IDE, and I want to add Git log information in a header file in order to use those in my software (print it in the terminal).

My whole project is ISO 8859-1 encoded, and Git uses the default UTF-8 for commit, so for log too.

The Git command I have is:

```
git log -n 1 --date=format:"%H:%M %d/%m/%Y" --encoding=ISO-8859-1 --pretty=format:"#ifndef GITCOMMIT_H_%n#define GITCOMMIT_H_%n%n#define AUTHOR_NAME '%an'%n#define COMMIT_HASH '%h'%n#define DATE '%cd'%n%n#endif"  > src\gitcommit.h
```

But when I compiled I got the error:

```
../gitcommit.h:1:1: error: stray '\377' in program
    1 | ÿþ# i f n d e f    G I T C O M M I T _ H _
```

And other errors all along the line.

How can I fix this?

As I am on Windows, when I create the header file with the ">" operator, it is automatically encoded in [UTF-16LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte-order_encoding_schemes).

Comment: Try running it in `git-bash`

Comment: What shell are you using? PowerShell?

Comment: Related (for the source code itself and for a UTF-8 [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)): *[Strange error in code: stray '\239', '\187', and '\191', and in program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626169/strange-error-in-code-stray-239-187-and-191-and-in-program/44626333#44626333)*

Comment: Related (for the source code itself and [UTF-16BE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte-order_encoding_schemes) instead of [UTF-16LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte-order_encoding_schemes)): *[How should I use g++'s -finput-charset compiler option correctly in order to compile a non-UTF-8 source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345802/how-should-i-use-gs-finput-charset-compiler-option-correctly-in-order-to-com)*

Comment: Possible duplicate: *['git log' output encoding issues in Windows 10 CLI terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139067/git-log-output-encoding-issues-in-windows-10-cli-terminal)*

Comment: Another option is *[Windows Terminal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-windows-terminal/)*.

Comment: [Some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139067/git-log-output-encoding-issues-in-windows-10-cli-terminal/41416262#41416262) mention the use of [environment variable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/environment_variable#Noun) `LC_ALL`.

Comment: What version of Windows? There was [a change in June 2019 to Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-can-i-use-unicode-characters-on-the-windows-command-line/56012091#56012091).

Comment: Where is the Git command run? In [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell)? In [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe)? From inside the IDE? Somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

[Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) is a version of [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), which should not tamper with the output of a command when redirecting its output to a file.

The most straightforward solution is:

- run your command in Git Bash

---

PowerShell applies some processing of programs' output without you asking.

The redirection operator `>`, for example, is not just a "plug the process' standard output to that file"; it calls the [Out-File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Out-File) cmdlet which *applies some processing on the output of your program* before actually writing it to a file.

Check if Out-File for your version of PowerShell supports a suitable encoding:
from the documentation for [Character encoding in PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_character_encoding?view=powershell-7.3#character-encoding-in-powershell). It looks like you need to have PowerShell >= 6.2 to be able to name [`windows-1252`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) as an encoding.

So another solution could be:

- check that your PowerShell version
- see if you can upgrade to >= 6.2
- set `windows-1252` as the encoding for your shell:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding']
```

Or just for one run:

```
... | Out-File -Encoding windows-1252 -FilePath src/git-commit.h
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, using the Git command I use in PowerShell differs in [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe).
In cmd, the output file encoding is UTF-8 which is still not ISO-8951-1, but it was finally OK for my use.

More particularly for STM32CubeIDE, the preprocessor shell can execute a *sh* script, so I don't have any encoding problem.

Comment: What is ISO-8951-1? Do you mean [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (it is in the question, incl. revision 1)?